# Fix Rotation of Origin

Tags: origin, transform-orientation

For some reason my origin's rotation got terribly messed up. I have been trying to fix it by aligning the origin to a face or a vertex but it only gets worse. I need to make an array and for that reason clean up the origin's rotation. Because as it is right now I don't get a regular and even offset.

I would be grateful for any input because I am out of ideas on how to fix it.

Thank you in advance!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you try CONTROL+A to apply transformations?

Comment: Yes, tried that. But the local always returns to a slightly tilted rotation.

Comment: can you share the blend file to check?

Answer (score 4):

It's 'easier' than it used to be, here's one way, using the 'View' Transform Orientation.

1. Find a reference rectangular face, preferably facing down your intended Z, select it in Edit Mode, and set the Transform Orientation to 'View'
2. Orthographic: <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Numpad 7</kbd> align your view to the face.
3. <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> > *Cursor to Selected* .. now the cursor should be centred on the face.
4. In Object Mode, with the Header > *Options* set to 'Origins', move the origin:  <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> > *Selected to Cursor*
5. Header > *Object*  > *Transform* menu.. *Align to Transform Orientation*. Now the Origin shoould be aligned with the view, and the face.

There may be some 90 degree swivels to do while in the view, to get your X,Y and Z on the right axes, and don't forget to switch the 'Origins' option off.

Comment: Thank you very much! Sorry for the late comment, missed the notification! :)